# How do I hide certain fields in the ShowingPopupEditForm programmatically in Devexpress

Tags: gridview, devexpress

I'm editing cells in a Devexpress gridview in a Form.  I chose to have a pop-up edit form open when I'm editing.  Now I don't want all the fields to show in the pop-up form.  How do I go about hiding certain fields in the ShowingPopupEditForm.  I would like to accomplish this in code.

See pic. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this :

```
gridView.Columns["columnName"].OptionsEditForm.Visible = DefaultBoolean.False;
```